# JavaFX: Add suffix to tableview data and maintain proper sorting

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I'm creating a tableview with some data from a database. To make the data more informative, I would like to add a suffix to it, e.g. ",-" after price (as integers) etc.

Now string concatenation would work fine to add this suffix (my columns take generic data types), but then the built-in sorting mechanism in tableview would start sorting the column as strings rather than integers (or other data types).

So, is there a way to add suffixes to integer values (or any data type for that matter) to a table column and still keep the sorting mechanism intact?

I searched the web before coming here, sadly without any luck.

Comment: What do you mean with "my colums take generc data types"? You need to place some restrictions on the data type to know where to insert the `,-`. Could you elaborate please? Maybe even post the code you're currently using for creating the column and relevant methods from the item class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you use a value type that implements `Comparable` (like `Integer` does) for the column and use the `cellFactory` to modify how the value is displayed:

```
public static class Item {

    private BigDecimal price;

    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public Item(BigDecimal price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
    TableColumn<Item, BigDecimal> column = new TableColumn<>();
    column.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("price"));
    column.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Item, BigDecimal>, TableCell<Item, BigDecimal>>() {

        private final Font font = Font.font("monospaced");
        private final BigDecimal hundred = BigDecimal.valueOf(100);
        private final char decimalSeparator = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getDecimalSeparator();

        @Override
        public TableCell<Item, BigDecimal> call(TableColumn<Item, BigDecimal> param) {
            return new TableCell<Item, BigDecimal>() {

                {
                    setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_RIGHT);
                    setFont(font);
                }

                @Override
                protected void updateItem(BigDecimal item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (empty || item == null) {
                        setText("");
                    } else {
                        BigInteger num = item.toBigInteger();
                        int frac = item.movePointRight(2).abs().remainder(hundred).intValue();
                        String numPart = String.format("%,d", num) + decimalSeparator;

                        setText(numPart + (frac == 0 ? "- " : String.format("%02d", frac)));
                    }
                }

            };
        }
    });

    table.getColumns().add(column);

    table.getItems().addAll(
            new Item(new BigDecimal("2")),
            new Item(new BigDecimal("2.5")),
            new Item(new BigDecimal("5555.99")),
            new Item(new BigDecimal("123456789.77")),
            new Item(new BigDecimal("22011.05")),
            new Item(new BigDecimal("4211"))
    );

    Scene scene = new Scene(table);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

(You could also use a custom `Comparator` as value for the [`comparator` property of `TableColumn`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumnBase.html#comparatorProperty) to specify how the values should be sorted; this can be used to treat `-` as `0` and ignore any group seperators, if necessary.)